Unity 2022.3.44f1 - ClassNotFoundException when initializing In-App Purchase
I'm using Unity 2022.3.44f1 with In-App Purchase version 4.12.2. When initializing the store, I'm encountering the following error:
2024.09.03 15:55:35.565 32028 32097 Error Unity AndroidJavaException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.billingclient.api.PurchasesUpdatedListener
2024.09.03 15:55:35.565 32028 32097 Error Unity java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.billingclient.api.PurchasesUpdatedListener
2024.09.03 15:55:35.565 32028 32097 Error Unity     at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
2024.09.03 15:55:35.565 32028 32097 Error Unity     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:536)
2024.09.03 15:55:35.565 32028 32097 Error Unity     at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.nativeRender(Native Method)
2024.09.03 15:55:35.565 32028 32097 Error Unity     at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.-$$Nest$mnativeRender(Unknown Source:0)
2024.09.03 15:55:35.565 32028 32097 Error Unity     at com.unity3d.player.B0.handleMessage(Unknown Source:122)
2024.09.03 15:55:35.565 32028 32097 Error Unity     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
2024.09.03 15:55:35.565 32028 32097 Error Unity     at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:230)
2024.09.03 15:55:35.565 32028 32097 Error Unity     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:319)
2024.09.03 15:55:35.565 32028 32097 Error Unity     at com.unity3d.player.C0.run(Unknown Source:24)
I'm also using Firebase and AdMob in my project.
What could be causing this ClassNotFoundException for com.android.billingclient.api.PurchasesUpdatedListener, and how can I resolve it? Are there any known conflicts between In-App Purchase, Firebase, and AdMob that might lead to this issue?
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!
What I've tried:
I've ensured that all my packages (Unity IAP, Firebase, and AdMob) are up to date.
I've double-checked that the Android SDK and JDK are properly set up in Unity.
I've tried cleaning and rebuilding the project.
Expected behavior:
I expected the store initialization to complete successfully without any exceptions.
